# Google Earth Engine: Error for mapping expression function over feature collection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, function

I'm having an issue when trying to create a function to map over a feature collection.

I'm trying to create SST thresholds for several regions where over a certain SST value is 1, under another SST, value is 0 and in between is a linear function between those cut offs.

I tried this with a single image first and it looked like it had worked. Link [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e8e49792daa4c85bd1d40939ea09050a)

However, I'd like to apply this to a featurecollection I've created , so I wanted to create a function of this and then map it over the collection. However I'm getting an error

```
Invalid argument specified for ee.List(): mean.
```

I think it is because I'm not defining mean correctly in the expression. I've tried lots of different options and can't figure it out. The code I'm using is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/35de5a2909cf539e89fe18460472434a)

```
var sst = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI').select('sst')
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.filterBounds(reefs_buffer)
.map(function(image){return image.clip(EEZ)}); //reefs_buffer

var sstMean = sst.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())

print('sstMean', sstMean)

var reefs_sstMean = sstMean.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  collection: reefs_buffer,
  scale: 30});

 print('reefs_sstMean', reefs_sstMean)

function sstHS_function(feature) {
   var sstReefs = feature.select('mean');
   var sstHS = sstReefs.expression(
"(b('mean') > 29.5) ? 1" +
 ": (b('mean')  < 24) ? 0" +
 ": 2/11*mean - 48/11 ",
 {'mean' : mean});
   return ee.Feature(sstHS);
 }

 var sstHS_collection = reefs_sstMean.map(sstHS_function)
 print(sstHS_collection)
 reefs_sstMean.map(sstHS_function)
```

Comment: Can't really check without access to your feature collections of the reefs, which have not been shared, but, my suspicion is that the error lies in your expression().

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of fiddling I managed to work out the issue. It turns out that rather I needed to apply the expression to the image collection, then calculate the means for the regions, rather than the other way around as I was doing initially.

So apply the expression to an image collection, then use the reduce functions to calculate the average expressions by time or region.